# Can't pass data via AJAX to Laravel

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I've met a problem that I can't pass a variable via AJAX to Laravel Controller. Here's my code:

AJAX function to submit an order:

```
function submitOrder() {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(order.positions));
    console.log('SENDING ORDER ',order.positions, ' to the database');
    event.preventDefault();
    // var id = this.id;
    var CSRF_TOKEN = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');
    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'Content-Type':'application/json',
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });

    $.ajax({
        //FIXME No response
        dataType: 'json',
        type: "post",
        url: '/orders/api/store',
        data: {
            _method: 'post',
            _token: CSRF_TOKEN,
            order: JSON.stringify(order.positions)
        },
        success: function( response ) {
            console.log(response);
        },
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert("Status: " + textStatus); alert("Error: " + errorThrown);
        }
    });
}
```

routes.php

```
Route::post('/orders/api/store', 'OrdersController@apiStore');
```

And Controller function:

```
public function apiStore(Request $request) {
    $response = [
        'request' => $request->order,
        'responseText' => 'works',
        'status' => '200'
    ];

    return response()->json($response); 
}
```

The response I'm getting:

```
SENDING ORDER  [{…}]0: 
    {product_id: 3, name: "Мороженое фрукты", price: "45.00", quantity: "1"}
    to the database // Sending this array
response {request: null, responseText: "works", status: "200"} //This is the response from Laravel
```

As you can see, the request variable is null, but it must be `$request->order` value, which was sent by AJAX.

Comment: Is 'order' a primary/foreign key?

Comment: Check your browser devtools - was `order` really POSTed?

Comment: @Don'tPanic yes, shows like passed successfully: Request Payload: _method=post&token=5hRAHn0Edzxv64gBRfMk0kLQHM8OaWYOaGtJpiHY&order=%5B%7B%22product_id%22%3A1%2C%22name%22%3A%22%D0%9C%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5+%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%22%2C%22price%22%3A%2251.00%22%2C%22quantity%22%3A%221%22%7D%5D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After 2 days of trying I've finally found the solving: create data variable (object), set if field with needed data and JSON.stringify it when passing to backend.

```
function submitOrder() {
console.log(JSON.stringify(order.positions));
console.log('SENDING ORDER ',order.positions, ' to the database');

var CSRF_TOKEN = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');
var data = {};
data.order = order.positions;
data._method = 'POST';
data._token = CSRF_TOKEN;
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '/orders/api/store/',
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    success: function( response ) {
        console.log(response);
    },
    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert("Status: " + textStatus); alert("Error: " + errorThrown);
    }
});
```

}

Answer (score 2):

I set up a fast prototype and this is a working example for me:

1. Laravel Back-end

```
// web.php

Route::post('/test', 'HomeController@test');
```

```
// HomeCrontroller.php

class HomeController extends Controller
{

   // ...

    public function test()
    {
      $response = [
        'request' => request()->data,
        'responseText' => 'works',
        'status' => '200'
      ];

      return response()->json($response);
    }

    // ...

}
```

2. Front-end

```
// some js

axios
    .post("/test", {
         data: {
             value: "key"
         }
     })
     .then(res => console.log(res));
```

```
// outcome of console.log(res)

{data: {…}, status: 200, statusText: "OK", headers: {…}, config: {…}, …}
config: {adapter: ƒ, transformRequest: {…}, transformResponse: {…}, timeout: 0, xsrfCookieName: "XSRF-TOKEN", …}
data:
request: {value: "key"}
responseText: "works"
status: "200"
// ...
```

If this doesn't work for you - check your versions.

Comment: It should work, i edited my answer and supplied a fully working example.

Comment: While it is great that you verified OPs code works, this is not an answer.

Comment: This is not OPs code. I tried to show how to set up the project properly and how to handle the request object in the right way.